# Adding full screen HERO image slideshow to a different Shopify page

Tags: css, shopify

I am trying to replicate my Shopify landing page a new page on my Shopify site. I have added a new page template and added the code to display the same image slideshow that is present on my home page. The issue is that it is not full width and the site header is above it as opposed to overlaid over the slideshow (see images).

I was planning on adding page specific CSS to make the slideshow full screen but I don't know how to overlay the site-header (main menu) and the CSS I have added to reduce the left and right margin (to make it full width) didn't work:

```
.page-ID-50282430575 div.wrapper {

  margin-left: 0px !important; margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image: How I would like it to look].
[image: This is how it currently looks]

Answer (score 0):

First, is your theme sectioned?
if yes try to find what section manage the image and add this to your new page template.

templates/page.custom.liquid

```
{% section 'slideshow' %}
```

after that you can manage this section directly in customize in the shopify admin.

Second, check your header section, some themes has options extra set for run only at index, my theme has this:

sections/header.liquid

```
{%- if template == 'index' and section.settings.enable_transparent_header -%}
  {%- assign use_transparent_header = true -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

add your new page template:

```
{%- if template == 'index' or template == 'page.custom' and section.settings.enable_transparent_header -%}
  {%- assign use_transparent_header = true -%}
{%- endif -%}
```

take care of header it can has many options set only for index you should extend all to your custom template

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214663/discussion-on-answer-by-pablote-adding-full-screen-hero-image-slideshow-to-a-dif).

Comment: @pablote I am trying to work through this conversation to do the same thing on another page but it isn't working. I would send you a PM don't think I can. Could you try to troubleshoot?